# JavaScript function does not work when used inside onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, variables, scope

I have a simple html link, in which I call a JavaScript function onClick and try to switch the value taken in. It's not working.

Here is my code:

```js
function lang(language) {
  switch (language) {
    case "it-IT":
      alert("Italiano selezionato");
      break;
    case "en-US":
      alert("English selected");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#" onClick="lang('en-US');">English</a></p>
<p><a href="#" onClick="lang('it-IT');">Italiano</a></p>
```

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: @LucasBaizer nope, no error in console (using Dreamweaver)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `lang` for your function name, the browser is using it already.

```js
function xlang(language) {
  switch (language) {
    case "it-IT":
      alert("Italiano selezionato");
      break;
    case "en-US":
      alert("English selected");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#" onClick="xlang('en-US');">English</a></p>
<p><a href="#" onClick="xlang('it-IT');">Italiano</a></p>
```

Comment: Isn't it possible for him to use the lang as long as he wraps it into a private function? Of course this is a better fix, but if he **really** wanted to use that function name?

Comment: it was exactly as you said, changing the function name solved the problem. Thank you, I didn't think about the global lang function..

Comment: When I run the snippet I still got both cases, it is a SO snippet problem ?

Comment: @Marcs What do you mean you got both cases? The snippet works fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry I was expecting only "Italiano selezionato" as result in the snippet and I didn't saw the alert function.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here. Around the `onclick` event handler there is used `with`, which allow you to use all global attributes (including `lang`) there. So it tries to access the global `lang` property.

So change you function name to anything else, but no `attributes` names

```html
<p><a href="#" onClick="alertLang('en-US');">English</a></p>
<p><a href="#" onClick="alertLang('it-IT');">Italiano</a></p>

<script>
  function alertLang(language) {
  switch (language) {
    case "it-IT":
      alert("Italiano selezionato");
      break;
    case "en-US":
      alert("English selected");
      break;
  }
}
  </script>
```

But it will work if you add it as a `event handler` in `Javascript`

```html
<p><a href="#">English</a></p>

<script>
  function lang() {
      alert("English selected");
  }
  
  document.querySelector('p').onclick = lang;
  </script>
```

Comment: Not the global lang.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign JavaScript code to the `onclick` handler, it is executed in a special scope where the properties of the element are available directly as is it were running inside a `with (element) { }` block.

In your example, the `lang` variable corresponds to the [`lang`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-lang) attribute of the element. Other examples that will cause the same error include [`id`, `title`, `style`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes) and `href`. Think of it as executing the following code:

```
function lang() {
}

with(element) {
    lang("en-US");
    // type error since lang resolves to element.lang
    // instead of the outer lang
}
```

You can simply namespace your function:

```javascript
var MyFancyFunctions {
    lang: function {
    }
};
```

```html
<a onclick="MyFancyFunctions.lang('en-US')">English</a>
```

Or just remove the ambiguity:

```html
<a onclick="window.lang('en-US')">English</a>
```

References:

The [internal raw uncompiled handler](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler)